# How to correct the size of Properties panel in Default window?

Tags: interface, properties

The Properties panel on RHS of default 3D window which is activated with (N) became very small and hard to read. All other active Blender files are fine....but cannot restore/resize to normal settings and too small to read.[image]

Comment: normally you can zoom in/out in it like in the 3D view (mouse wheel or numpad+/-). That does not work for you ?

Comment: try ctrl + middle mouse button (not rotating wheel, only click) and drag mouse up/down

Comment: Scroll wheel works in 3D window but only moves the Properties panel up or down.....numPad is the same!

Comment: and you have the mouse cursor on this panel when you do it ? You can try "home" also to restore to the default size

Comment: Control+ middle mouse corrected the problem Thanks Shubol3D    and also Lemon for efforts!